# Why wasn't Yosef's wife counted in the 70 people of Yaakov's family that went down to Egypt?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers

Some say that they were 66 and that the missing 4 are: Yocheved, Yosef and his 2 sons. How about Osnas (Dina's daughter, Yosef's wife). If Yosef and his children were counted why not Osnas?

Comment: It says מלבד נשי בני יעקב

Comment: @shlomy however, I was going to reply to doubleaa noting that that passuk is only said about the 66, not the 70, in which case there is no issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117748/discussion-between---and-shlomy).

Comment: An astute observation @רבות but Yosef himself is mentioned with the 66 so his wife could be included in that line. It certainly fits the spirit of the count, not to include wives separately. In any event very close readings of the text are very unlikely to provide any single compelling Pshat answer here, so in the end we're stuck with the same handful of plausible guesses. For all we know asenat was dead by then or something.

Comment: @DoubleAA 1. what do you mean by "mentioned with them"? His children and wife are also "mentioned with them". 2. I'm not disagreeing with your pshat methodology, I'm simply noting that the verse which you brought doesn't conclusively exclude this possibility.

Answer (score 6):

A¹ according to the Tur on Torah you can say Asnas was the 70th.
A² according to chachmei Tzarfas and Chizkuni in parshas Emor by the ger you can say since Asnas father was Shchem therefore she wasn't Jewish or related to Dina.
A³ according to the Moshav Zikeinim she wouldn't be listed because the count doesn't include the wives of the children of Yakov.
A⁴ according to the Taima Dikra that Serach bas Asher was really the daughter of Ashers wife and reason she's counted is because since Asher raised her it's as if he gave birth to her. Can say since Potifar raised Asnas she's considered his daughter and not Dinas.
A⁵ according to the Pirkei Drav Eliezer Asnas went to Egypt just to marry Yosef, so one can say she's not counted since didn't go to Egypt because of the shibud or slavery.

Comment: Great answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think she is counted, just not expressly for the same reason she is never expressly described as Dinah's daughter--the story of her conception is an embarrassment to her mother.

We all know the question that if you count the names of Yaakov's family there are only 69 names. There are two primary answers to this question in the Rishonim: 1) Rashi, quoting the Gemara, says that **the 70th is Yocheved**; 2) the Ramban and Ibn Ezra say that **the 70th is Yakov himself**.  Each of this answers has weaknesses.

**1. Yocheved as the 70th**

A) If Yocheved is the 70th, why not say her name expressly? Pesukim elsewhere expressly say she was the daughter of Levi (Bamidbar 26:59; Shemos 6:20).

B) If Yocheved is the 70th, she gave birth to Miriam when she was 125, Aharon at 127, and Moshe at 130. Why is this incredible miracle not mentioned in the posuk?

**2. Yaakov as the 70th**

A) Yaakov makes sense if one only looks at the end of the parsha because he is not יֹצְאֵ֣י יְרֵכ֔וֹ and therefore not part of the 66 that went down (Bereishis 46:26) but is part of כָּל־הַנֶּ֧פֶשׁ לְבֵֽית־יַעֲקֹ֛ב (Bereishis 46:27). But that count isn't the only issue. By the count of the children of Leah it says:

> אֵ֣לֶּה ׀ בְּנֵ֣י לֵאָ֗ה אֲשֶׁ֨ר יָֽלְדָ֤ה לְיַעֲקֹב֙ בְּפַדַּ֣ן
> אֲרָ֔ם וְאֵ֖ת דִּינָ֣ה בִתּ֑וֹ כָּל־נֶ֧פֶשׁ בָּנָ֛יו וּבְנוֹתָ֖יו
> שְׁלֹשִׁ֥ים וְשָׁלֹֽשׁ

> These are the children of Leah that she bore to Yaakov in Padan Aram
> and with Dinah her daughter all the souls of his sons and daughters,
> 33.
> (Bereishis 46:15)

But if you count the names of Leah's children there are only 32, not 33. Yocheved fits as she was a daughter of Levi. But how can Yaakov himself be counted as one of his children from Leah?

So we need another option that fits with all of the pesukim.

**3. Osnas as the 70th**

Counting Osnas as the 70th member of Yaakov's family explains all of the pesukim. Osnas is not mentioned expressly because of the embarrassing circumstances of her conception and adoption. She is counted among the children of Leah in Bereshis 46:15 because she is daughter of Dina. She is not counted among the 66 that went down in Bereishis 46:26 because she was already in Egypt. But she is counted in Bereishis 46:27 as part of the 70 just like her husband and her husband, Yosef, and her sons.

Answer (score 0):

Not ignoring the previous answers, but just adding a thought *al pi drush*.

The sefer Chesed Shmuel (I think it is) says that it was only permissible for Yosef to marry Osnas because he was in *chutz la'aretz* (using the same logic that it was only permissible for Yaakov to marry sisters because he was in *chutz la'aretz*.

Therefore you could not possibly say that Osnas was one of the 70 who came to *Mitzrayim*, because to the extent she was *shayach* to *Eretz Yisrael* she was forbidden to Yosef.

Comment: Can you please explain why Yosef wasn't allowed to marry her in Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: @Shlomy I think the Chesed Shmuel (if that was the *sefer*) assumes that Osnas was the daughter of Potiphar, and the *ta'anah* seems to be something to do with marrying a *Mitzri*. If Osnas was Dina's daughter from Shechem, I do not imagine this was the greatest *yichus* either.

Comment: If you are right Osnas wouldn't be mentioned because she was potifars daughter,  not Dinas.

Comment: @Shlomy Agreed. The relevant *sevara* is that there was a *kepeida* on Yosef's choice of wife vis-a-vis *Eretz Yisrael*.

Comment: That kpeida only mattered if asnas wasn't bas dina.

Comment: @Shlomy But even if Asnas was bas Dina she was still sent away from the family in Eretz Yisrael.

Comment: If you want to say that as an answer we can cler on that. However what you wrote as an answer is a different logic... It wouldn't be asur to marry her for that reason. Therefore he could've even done it in eretz yisrael.

Comment: @Shlomy But it could have been *lo na'im*